# Fazer consulta no banco de dados enviar e usar no javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

A minha dificuldade é após enviar para o java script como separar cada registro:

Exemplo:
No meu código estou rodando está função:

```
$culturas=array();
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexao,"select *from mandioca_iea where id_cult=1");
            while($cultura=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado))
            {
                array_push($culturas,$cultura);
            }
        echo json_encode($culturas);
```

E para receber a consulta:

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {}
```

Até ai tudo certo,ele envia para o Javascript algo assim:

No meu console retornou isso :`[{"iea_id":"1","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0"‌​, "man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0","man_ins_area_‌​13":"0", "man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"1","id_cult":"1"}, {"iea_id":"2","man_ins_area_00":"0","man_ins_prod_00":"0","man_ins_area_05":"0", "man_ins_prod_05":"0","man_ins_area_10":"0","man_ins_prod_10":"0", "man_ins_area_13":"0","man_ins_prod_13":"0","id_cid":"2","id_cult":"1"}]`

Onde :"iea_id":"1" e "iea_id":"2",são dois registros diferentes.

Minha **dúvida** é se existe alguma maneira de **acessar** os "registros"(pois nesse formato não são mais registros),**separadamente**,**como se fosse um vetor**,para montagem de um gráfico?

EDITANDO COM O ERRO:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código completo que está sendo usado:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function($) {
    $("#formulario").submit(function() {
        $("#status").html("<img src='loader.gif' alt='Enviando' />");
        $.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {
    for(var i=0; i<resposta.length; i++) {
        var registro = resposta[i];
        console.log(registro.iea_id);
    }
});
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você tem uma array de objetos. Os colchetes definem a array, e cada par de `{` e `}` define um objeto (um para cada registro). Você acessa os registros fazendo um loop na array:

```
$.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {
    for(var i=0; i<resposta.length; i++) {
        var registro = resposta[i];
        console.log(registro.iea_id); // 1 na primeira passada, 2 na segunda
    }
});
```

É simples assim, dentro do loop você pode acessar os campos pelo nome/chave.

Quanto à montagem do gráfico, você pode reprocessar os dados no JavaScript e reorganizá-los para passar ao gerador de gráficos, ou já passar no formato certo desde o PHP. Depende de você precisar ou não dos dados completos (e organizados por registro) no JS.

Comment: Quando eu rodo o código no meu console aparece apenas:166 undefined. Nessa linha: console.log(registro.iea_id); // 1 na primeira passada, 2 na segunda,tem ideia do que seja?

Comment: Os dados são aqueles que estão na pergunta mesmo? Parece que o primeiro ID vem 166, e o segundo em branco.

Comment: Os dados são aqueles, só que eu coloquei 2 apenas, na vdd ele retorna +- 600 registros, vou editar o post com uma imagem do erro pra vc entender melhor

Comment: Editado como código completo e imagem do erro

Comment: você pode dar um `console.log(typeof resposta)`?

Comment: Da esse erro:" Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Comment: Tem certeza, você escreveu como no meu comentário? Esse erro aí não deveria ser gerado pelo código que eu falei.

Comment: coloquei isso:$("#status").html("<img src='loader.gif' alt='Enviando' />");
  
  $.post('envia.php', {nome: nome}, function(resposta) {
  console.log(typeof resposta);
.O erro que deu foi esse: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocationjquery.js:6 x.param.ojquery.js:6 gnjquery.js:6 gnjquery.js:6 gnjquery.js:6 x.paramjquery.js:6 x.extend.ajaxjquery.js:6 x.each.x.(anonymous function)index2.php:43 (anonymous function)jquery.js:5 x.event.dispatchjquery.js:5 x.event.add.v.handle

Comment: Cara, não sei o que pode estar acontecendo, tenta um `resposta = $.parseJSON(resposta)` antes do loop.

Comment: Para funcionar a unica biblioteca que precisa é a do jquery né?

Comment: É, só jQuery...